# Change date from YYYYMMDD to "DD/MM/YYYY" by concatenating string variables for day, month and year

Tags: excel, vba, concatenation

I have data which I have extracted from a CSV.

In a cell is a date YYYYMMDD. For example 22020705.

I need it to be "DD/MM/YYYY".

```vb
For i = 1 To lastRow
    cbhDate = Cells(i, 62)
    resultYear = Left(cbhDate, 4)
    resultDay = Right(cbhDate, 2)
    resultMonth = Mid(cbhDate, 5, 2)
    Cells(i, 62) = resultDay & "/" & resultMonth & "/" & resultYear
Next i
```

The output in the cell is 7/05/2022 instead of 05/07/2022.
The number format in the column changes automatically to Date.
My PC is set to Australian date settings.

If I add

```vb
Cells(i, 62).NumberFormat = "DD/MM/YYYY"
```

to the end of this section of code, it does not make a difference.

Comment: Have you tried setting the numberformat BEFORE setting the value?

Comment: Rather than building a string that only looks like a date, and is ambiguous,  create an actual date, using the [`DATE`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/date-function-e36c0c8c-4104-49da-ab83-82328b832349) function

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

```
Sub ChangeDateFormat()

    Dim Lastrow As Integer
    
    Lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Change this column as needed
    
    For i = 1 To Lastrow

        Cells(i, 62).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Format` and `DateValue` to convert the text date to a true date:

```vb
Dim i As Long
Dim r As Range

For i = 1 To lastRow
    Set r = Cells(i, 62)
    r.Value = DateValue(Format(r.Value, "@@@@\/@@\/@@"))
    r.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
Next

Set r = Nothing
```